# Absolute difference between variables in columns of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**EDIT:::::**
So I need to employ this for x and y coordinates. So DF1 has 5384167 pairs and the DF2 has 1928 pairs.

I understand how @Divakar 's solution works for one variable. In my specific case I have Subway Coordinates and I'd like to compare their proximity to Crime Coordinates. See if there is a correlation with type of crime and euclidean distance from the closest Subway Station.

I know that sqrt(DF1[x]-DF2[x])**2 + (DF1[y]-DF2[y])**2) needs to be done between all X,Y's in subway locations and each X, Y in crime locations.

Crime Coordinates:

`X_COORD_CD  Y_COORD_CD
0   1007314.0    241257.0
1   1043991.0    193406.0
2    999463.0    231690.0
3   1060183.0    177862.0
4    987606.0    208148.0`

Subway Coordinates:

`X_COORD_CD  Y_COORD_CD
0   1020671.0    248680.0
1   1019420.0    245867.0
2   1017558.0    245632.0`

`X_Crime    Y_Crime   X_Subway  Y_Subway   Dist_sub1    Dist_sub2   Dist_sub3
1007314     241257    1020671   248680     13356.72213  12105.8096  10243.78646
1043991     193406    1019420   245867     23318.81485  24569.93244 26432.01209
999463      231690    1017558   245632     21207.59944  19956.64481 18094.61475
1060183     177862                         39511.10383  40762.16584 42624.20504
987606      208148                         33064.38708  31813.40719 29951.37426`

so Dist_sub1[0] = ((X_Crime[0] - X_Subway[0])**2 + (Y_Crime[0] - Y_Subway[0])**2)**0.5

Dist_sub2[3] = ((X_Crime[3] - X_Subway[1])**2 + (Y_Crime[3] - Y_Subway[1])**2)**0.5

So the minimum distance to a subway for Crime[0] is 10243.78646 (Subway[2]); Crime[1] is 23318.81485 (Subway[0]); Crime[2] is 18094.61475 (Subway[2]); Crime[3] is 39511.10383 (Subway[0]); Crime[4] is 29951.37426 (Subway[2])

**END OF EDIT**

I have a list of x and y coordinates in two separate dataframes. One has 5384167 entries and the other has 1928 entries.

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the absolute distance between each entry in df1 and df2, then find the minimum. Example:

df1 :

```
x
1
2
3
```

df2 :

```
x
4
5
6
7
```

I know creating a matrix is the way to go but I literally do not know how to get there. The matrix would look like this:

```
3   2   1
4   3   2
5   4   3
6   5   4
```

Then I'd get the minimum for each column :

```
3   2   1
```

Comment: Could you show us a sample case where the sorting at the first step is messing up/not giving the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar sorry about that. I will edit the original post and actually include a real sample of each list.

Comment: Also, do add the expected output if you haven't already.

Comment: @Divakar I have added the formula and the outcome I want. Just the minimum distance, or the distance to the closest subway station.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches could be suggested.

**Approach #1**

One approach with [`NumPy broacasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with heavy memory requirements would be  -

```
def abs_min_broadcasting(a, b): # a, b are input arrays
    return np.abs(a[:,None]-b).min(axis=0)

output = abs_min_broadcasting(df2.x.values, df1.x.values)
```

**Approach #2**

Another memory efficient one and as such faster one would be with `np.searchsorted` -

```
def abs_min_searchsorted(a, b): # a, b are input arrays
    a_s = np.sort(a) # skip this if already sorted
    lidx = np.searchsorted(a_s,b).clip(max=len(a_s)-1)
    ridx = (lidx-1).clip(min=0)
    return np.minimum( np.abs(a_s[lidx] - b), np.abs(a_s[ridx] - b) )

output = abs_min_searchsorted(df2.x.values, df1.x.values)
```

Sample run -

```
In [866]: df1
Out[866]: 
   x
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [867]: df2
Out[867]: 
   x
0  4
1  5
2  6
3  7

In [869]: abs_min_broadcasting(df2.x.values, df1.x.values)
Out[869]: array([3, 2, 1])

In [870]: abs_min_searchsorted(df2.x.values, df1.x.values)
Out[870]: array([3, 2, 1])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [872]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(0,100,(10000))})

In [873]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(0,100,(1000))})

In [874]: %timeit abs_min_broadcasting(df2.x.values, df1.x.values)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.4 ms per loop

In [875]: %timeit abs_min_searchsorted(df2.x.values, df1.x.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 663 µs per loop

In [876]: out1 = abs_min_searchsorted(df2.x.values, df1.x.values)
     ...: out2 = abs_min_broadcasting(df2.x.values, df1.x.values)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
     ...: 
True
```